# Using transpose with arrays in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, transpose

I have the following:

```
table(
  [
    [
      "UnitID",
      "First Name",
      "Last Name",
      "NPS Score",
      "Comments",
      "emotion",
      "polarity"
    ],
    *[
      invite_unitid_arr,
      invite_name_arr,
      invite_lastname_arr,
      nps_score_integers,
      comment_arr,
      SadPanda.emotion(comment_arr),
      SadPanda.polarity(comment_arr)
    ].transpose
  ]
)
```

However, `SadPanda.emotion(comment_arr)` and `SadPanda.polarity(comment_arr)` return:

```
undefined method 'gsub!' for #<Array:0x007f8f9b0d40a8>
```

How can I transpose the array but also use `SadPanda.emotion()` on each string value within the array?

EDIT:

To be clear, this is what I want as an end result:

```
[
invite_unitid_arr[0],
invite_name_arr[0],
invite_lastname_arr[0],
nps_score_integers[0],
comment_arr[0],
SadPanda.emotion(comment_arr[0]),
SadPanda.polarity(comment_arr[0])
],

[
invite_unitid_arr[1],
invite_name_arr[1],
invite_lastname_arr[1],
nps_score_integers[1],
comment_arr[1],
SadPanda.emotion(comment_arr[1]),
SadPanda.polarity(comment_arr[1])
]
```

Etc. etc. The `.transpose` method does exactly what I need it to do for all values in the array, but I don't know how to pass in `comment_arr[0]` on the `.emotion` and `.polarity` methods and increment that value each time the array is transposed.

Comment: ...what is `SadPanda`?

Comment: Ha, it's a gem designed for sentiment analysis. I want to return the `emotion` of each comment beside that comment in a table.

Comment: If you execute `SadPanda.emotion(comment_arr) and SadPanda.polarity(comment_arr)` outside of `table` (where `comment_arr` is a string) do they work correctly? Is `table` a method?  You have the `splat` operator inside one array and outside of another.  Is that what you want?

Comment: `SadPanda.emotion(comment_arr[0])` works correctly, as well as the polarity method. `table` is a method which generates a table within a pdf file. The `splat` operator is correct as well. I just need to loop over the array `comment_arr` while performing `SadPanda.emotion` on each value, at the same time as the `transpose` method.

Comment: But in `table` the argument for `SadPanda.emotion` (and `.polarity`) is `comment_arr`, not `comment_arr[0]`.

Comment: I understand that. I need to loop over `comment_arr`, so the argument should be `comment_arr[0], comment_arr[1], etc` for each transposed array. I know I can do a `comment_arr.each do |x|...` but I need it to happen as the table is being created. I need to transpose the array as seen above while looping through the array to get the `.emotion` and `.polarity` on each value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue:

```
new_comment_array_emotion = []
new_comment_array_polarity = []

comment_arr.each do |x|
    new_comment_array_emotion << SadPanda.emotion(x)
    new_comment_array_polarity << SadPanda.polarity(x)
end

table(
  [
    [
      "UnitID",
      "First Name",
      "Last Name",
      "NPS Score",
      "Comments",
      "emotion",
      "polarity"
    ],
    *[
      invite_unitid_arr,
      invite_name_arr,
      invite_lastname_arr,
      nps_score_integers,
      comment_arr,
      new_comment_array_emotion,
      new_comment_array_polarity
    ].transpose
  ]
)
```

Feel free to propose a cleaner way of doing this within Ruby.